# Pull up or pull down resistor for potentially unused inverter input?

Tags: pcb, resistors, circuit-design, integrated-circuit

I'm using this [TI Inverter](https://www.digikey.com/en/products/detail/texas-instruments/SN74LS06DR/562907) that mandates that the unused inputs never float.

Sometimes, the inputs will NOT be used, and other times, all 6 will be used.

As such, it seems like I should use a pull up/down resistor in the case where only some of the 6 inputs are being used.

Should it be a pull up or a pull down? Does it matter? I'm thinking about using a 1K resistor since I care about speed here (on the order of ~200us).

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Generally, for LS TTL, a pull up makes slightly more sense. Usually that is because before LS TTL ICs, there were other TTL ICs and those consumed much less current with a signal that mostly idles high with a pull-up rather than with a signal that mostly idles low with a pull-down.

Otherwise, the datasheet says to pull to VCC or GND, whichever makes more sense. But it also links to a CMOS specific application note, which may not be relevant for LS TTL.

Comment: Apparently TTL is susceptible to latch-up if pulled hard to VCC; it's possible they've been changed to avoid this failure mechanism, but it seems a little more likely to me that some application engineers just don't know this about them anymore? *shrug* In any case, pull-up resistor will be fine.

Answer (score 1):

From the [data sheet](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/sn74ls06.pdf?HQS=dis-dk-null-digikeymode-dsf-pf-null-wwe&ts=1701726599321&ref_url=https%253A%252F%252Fwww.ti.com%252Fgeneral%252Fdocs%252Fsuppproductinfo.tsp%253FdistId%253D10%2526gotoUrl%253Dhttps%253A%252F%252Fwww.ti.com%252Flit%252Fgpn%252Fsn74ls06), the magnitude of the input high current is much less than the input low current. So pull-up resistors are my choice.

[image]

LSTTL has an [input capacitance of about 5pF](https://ecelabs.njit.edu/fed101/resources/Motorola_Short_Version.pdf). So to realize the full speed of the device, the pull-up resistance should be less than 500 ohms.

[image]